# Error buildling with maven for openshift

Tags: java, maven, openshift

This is my POM.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>myapp</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.executable>${env.OPENSHIFT_WILDFLY_DIR}usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/javac</maven.compiler.executable>
    <maven.compiler.fork>true</maven.compiler.fork>

    <spring.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.34</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when invoking mvn. -->
        <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app will need. -->
        <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' folder. -->
        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>myapp</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

When I am building using mvn package I am getting

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building myapp 1.0
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ myapp ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 1 resource

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ myapp ---
Compiling 1 source file to D:\git\myapp\target\classes
-------------------------------------------------------------
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
The system cannot find the path specified.

1 error
-------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.711s
Finished at: Wed Dec 31 13:15:42 IST 2014
Final Memory: 6M/15M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project myapp: Compilation failure
Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
The system cannot find the path specified.
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

what could be the issue?

Comment: execute `mvn clean install -e -X` and post the error stacktrace here

Comment: and what is your JAVA_HOME pointing to `echo $JAVA_HOME` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem with our group project. Particularly this line is breaking your build:

```
<maven.compiler.executable>${env.OPENSHIFT_WILDFLY_DIR}usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/javac</maven.compiler.executable>
```

its specifying the path to javac to compile java files. However, this line above point to a fixed path (which isn't same on all computers). Remove it, and your local build will pass. However, I'm suspecting if you remove that line it might break something on openshift side, though.